# Are there any differences in graphics drivers from the "X-Swat" vs. "xorg-edgers" PPAs?

Tags: nvidia, ati, package-management, ppa

Are there any differences between nvidia-graphics-drivers 304.43 from x-swap PPA and x-edgers PPA, or is it the same package?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- If the version numbers for graphics driver packages are the same, there is no difference between the [*X-Swat* (X-Updates) PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) and the [*xorg-edgers* PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa/+packages) (because they come from the same source)
- **But**, note that the *X-Swat* PPA contains only graphics driver packages, while the *xorg-edgers* PPA also contains many other "bleeding-edge" graphics/system packages which may be unstable; if you choose the *xorg-edgers* PPA, regular updates will install these other packages too.
- So, if you want to update only your graphics drivers, the **[*X-Swat* (X-Updates) PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) is recommended.**

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, x-swat is quite outdated, so I think is better to use xorg-edgers. At least they have a saucy version

Comment: x-swat has up-to-date packages, at least for 17.04.